# Why don't Automatic additions to Other Contacts happen as they should?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Gmail has a setting "When I send a message to a new person, add them to Other Contacts so that I can auto-complete to them next time."  (The opposite is "I'll add contacts myself," i.e. manually.)

Mine stopped working, after a friend tried to set up my email for me on a cell phone and totally screwed things up.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and would like to record it here in case anyone else ever has this problem.

Look at your Google Contacts and check that the folder "Other Contacts" exists.  If not, that's the problem!  Recreate it, and voilà, your new correspondents will automatically be added to your contacts, and autocomplete will work in the compose window as it should.